# Is there a way to customize git commit message in gulp.js task runner

Tags: javascript, git, gulp

I have implemented gulp.js into my current project build and I'm using gulp-git. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way I can allow the user the option of entering a unique commit message after typing the 'gulp commit' command in the terminal. Is this possible?

Here is the current gulp task.

```
gulp.task('commit', function(){
  gulp.src('./*', {buffer:false})
  .pipe(git.commit('initial commit'));
});
```

I am using the gulp-git package https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `gulp-prompt` which appears to be what your looking for:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-prompt

I haven't tested this, but something like this should work:

Install gulp-prompt `npm install gulp-prompt`

Then edit your gulp task.

```
gulp.task('commit', function(){
    var message;
    gulp.src('./*', {buffer:false})
    .pipe(prompt.prompt({
        type: 'input',
        name: 'commit',
        message: 'Please enter commit message...'
    }, function(res){
        message = res.commit;
    }))
    .pipe(git.commit(message));
});
```

Comment: Gulp-prompt is exactly what I was looking for thank you!

Comment: Your solution is definitely the answer I've been looking for, but I seem to be getting some strange errors when I run the command.   

TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
  at Object.module.exports [as commit]

I tried google but there doesn't seem to be any solution, do you have any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: Still stuck on this issue, it seems to be working. The terminal just seems to display a number of errors before the option to type the commit message is displayed. @RichardMacarthy Can you please test it and see if you get a similar error?